# Not getting BGP Notification with Optional Attribute Error

Tags: python, sockets, scapy, bgp, quagga

i am working with BGP implementation with Ubuntu, for the testing purpose i want to get 'notification message'  indicating 'optional attribbute error'.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import socket
import time
BGP_IP = '20.0.0.20'

MSG1 = (b'\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff'
        b'\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff'
        b'\x00\x35'
        b'\x01'                  #open message
        b'\x04'
        b'\x00\x64'
        b'\x00\xb4'
        b'\x01\x01\x01\x01'
        b'\x18'
        b'\x02\x06\x01\x04\x00\x01\x00\x01\x02\x02\x80'
        b'\x00\x02\x02\x02\x00\x02\x06\x41\x04\x00\x00\x00\x64')

MSG2 = (b'\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff'
        b'\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff'
        b'\x00\x13'
        b'\x04')                #keepalive 

MSG3 = (b'\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff'     # First 8 bytes of marker
        b'\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff'     # last 8 bytes
        b'\x00\x36'                             # length
        b'\x02'                                 # update packate
        b'\x00\x00'                             # withdrawn routes
        b'\x00\x1c'
        b'\x40\x01\x01\x00'
        b'\x50\x02\x00\x06\x02\x01\x00\x00\x00\x64'
        b'\x40\x03\x04\x14\x00\x00\x0a'
        b'\x80\x04\x04\x00p\x00\x00\x00'  #(malformed optional attribs)
        b'\x10\x0a\00')


def main():
     sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
     print("Socket created")
     sock.connect((BGP_IP, 179))
     print("Socket connected")
     sock.send(MSG1)   #open message
     time.sleep(5)
     sock.send(MSG2)   #keepalive
     time.sleep(5)
     print("connection has been established")
     sock.send(MSG3)   #malformed update
     while True:
         data = sock.recv(1)
         if data==b'':
             print("Connection closed or reset")
             break
         print("Received:", data)

sock.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

i am using python socket programming.here in my code, I am first sending open message than getting response in terms of open-keepalive and than sending keepalive to establish the bgp session between Router-A and DUT.

anyway, after connection establishment i am sending malformed update packet ( having malformation in optional attribute ) , it supposed to send notification message with error 'optional attribute error' , but it is not sending that error message. now my concern is how to receive that 'Notification Message' having error code ' Optional Attribute Error'.

......

Comment: Is the BGP session in established state before sending the update message? From the logs bgpd is in opensent state which means it is waiting for open message from its peer.

Comment: Yes, to eliminate that error i come up with the idea that to send keepalive first ( i tried with sending open but i dont know connection was getting rejected ) and wait for 5 sec. After that i am sending that malformed packet, which is accepted well by other side but i don't know why it is sending RST before sending notification. @Vivek S

Comment: To get to state ESTABLISHED, you need to send an OPEN first.  Sending a KEEPALIVE is not sufficient.  Also, you should expect that the first received message is an OPEN (and not the NOTIFICATION from the other side).

Comment: As per your guidance, I am able to establish the connection. now I am stuck in proper malformation, I am not able to do that malformation. @BrunoRijsman

Comment: hello, @VivekS     finally the session has been established but I don't know the proper malformation in update packet. Do you have any idea about that ? can you help me into that? also see my updated question

Comment: What are you receiving when you send the malformed update message? Do you have a wireshark trace to look at? What BGP implementation are you using?

Comment: @VivekS Thanks for the reply, i got it resolved. there was some RFC issue. because i was looking for 'Optional Attribute Error' when Cisco and other guys are saying that instead of that generic error we will give a specific error like 'Flag Error' or 'Length Error'. [here you can find it] (http://pike.lysator.liu.se/docs/ietf/rfc/42/rfc4276.xml)